# Зачем нужны классы AbstractCollection, AbstractList, AbstractSet, и т.п., и используются ли они где нибудь?

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть иерархия классов или что-то в этом роде.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для Queue и Map тоже самое. Зачем нужны эти второстепенные классы?
Почему нельзя определить что-бы ArrayList реализовывал  List?
И самый главный вопрос, используются где нибудь в программировании эти второстепенные классы? Если что-то не понятно пишите в комментарии.
P.S Сейчас Vector используется,или только Stack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Зачем нужны эти второстепенные классы?**

Для того чтобы классы более низкой иерархии создавались бы проще, имели бы меньше кода. Это абстрактные классы-каркасы, на которых строятся их раализации. Конечно, можно реализовать конкретные классы непосредственно от интерфейсов. Но это потребовало бы укрупнения классов-реализаций (чтобы добиться аналогичного функционала).

Все эти классы являются  частью  [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html), цель которого дать максимальную гибкость в работе.

**Где используются**

Все эти "втростепенные" классы активно используются в Java SE для реализации различного функционала.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А программировании они используются?

Comment: Я именю ввиду используются ли они напрямую в коде программистами?

Comment: @антонсорокин Да, используются. Весьма активно. Например, для создания "своих" ArrayList-реализаций [We can wrap an internal ArrayList and add some control on it](http://makble.com/when-to-use-abstractlist), [jbos](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243653?_sscc=t), [sap](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/1758774#1758774).